# How do i resolve the procedure entry point_impure_ptr error in cygwin/opencobol?

Tags: cygwin, exe, cobol

Whenever I try to run my .exe cobol file, i get this error..

> fileName.exe Entry Point Not Found
>   The procedure entry point_impure_ptr could not be located in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll

I am using OpenCObol and cygwin ver1.7.15.thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to specify the proper path for the command below, but Cygwin seems pretty persnickety with entry point addresses and updates,  The system includes a **rebaseall** command to help fix this problem.  Most times I've witnessed it is after a **setup.exe pass**, while the Cygwin system was still active (and perhaps only in the background and not visible).

```
C:\Users\btiffin\cygwin\bin\dash -c '/usr/bin/rebaseall'
```

Run that from a Windows CMD shell (while Cygwin isn't active, say after a clean boot and before running the Cygwin shell. Basically cygwin1.dll can't be open).  You'll need to use the proper Windows path to **dash** for your particular install.  Google Cygwin rebase for detailed articles.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message after upgrading from cygwin version 1.5 to 1.7.  I solved it by completely removing and reinstalling 1.7 from scratch.  I was told there might have been a problem with multiple versions of dlls.